# vim YouCompleteMe GoTo does not work

Tags: c++, vim

I am using YouCompleteMe for c++ stuff and the code completion works perfectly but all YcMCompleter sub-commands GoTo* does not work. It says "Can't jump to declaration or definition"

Is there something I missed? Any option that I haven't set?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you post this on the plugin's issue tracker?!

Comment: you need to add your "include" path of your project to configuration file of ycm. Have you done that?

Answer (score 3):

To make the GoTo* commands work on my C++ project I had to use the wonderful [YCM-Generator](https://github.com/rdnetto/YCM-Generator) to generate the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file and make sure that I was including everything I needed.

YouCompleteMe has one important limitation: while the `GoToDefinition` command works fine, the `GoToDeclaration` will only work in some cases:

> NOTE: For C-family languages this only works in certain situations, namely when the definition of the symbol is in the current translation unit. A translation unit consists of the file you are editing and all the files you are including with #include directives (directly or indirectly) in that file.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gotodefinition-subcommand).